# Unityで衝突判定のスクリプトで物体を消したい

Tags: c#, unity3d

Unityでビリヤードのようなゲームを作っていて、球（Sphere）がホール（Cylinder）に当たったら消えるようにしたいのですが、書いてみたスクリプトがエラーもせず何も反応しませんでした。改善個所をご指摘いただけるとありがたいです。

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class myscript : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        GameObject sphere = GameObject.Find("Sphere");
        Rigidbody rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();    
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player"){
            collision.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: このような感じになっています]

Answer (score 1):

以下の仮定で話します。

球（Sphere）: Playerタグと`Rigidbody`コンポーネントが付いていて移動する。myscriptスクリプトが付いている
ホール（Cylinder）: `Rigidbody`コンポーネントが付いておらず移動しない

`OnCollisionEnter`メソッドは、`Rigidbody`を持つオブジェクトが**衝突したオブジェクト**を引数の`Collision`クラスとして返します。
すなわち、球がホールに衝突した時は`collision`の値にホールが入ります。

下記のコードで1.を実行すると、ホールにPlayerタグが付いていればホールが消えます。
myscriptをSphereに付けているならば、`this`でSphere自身を取得して消すことができます。
下記コードの2.に書き換えて目的にそった動作になるかどうか確認してください。

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    //1. 動いているオブジェクトが「ぶつかった」オブジェクトのタグがPlayerの時、Playerが消える
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        collision.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    //2. 「動いている」オブジェクトのタグがPlayerの時、ぶつかったPlayer自身が消える
    if (this.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

どちらかのオブジェクトの`Is Trigger`にチェックが入っていると、`OnCollisionEnter`が発生せずに`OnTriggerEnter`が発生するようになります。
上記コードで動かない場合は下記の内容についても確認してみてください。

[image: 確認事項]

Comment: 大変参考になりました！ありがとうございます。